# In $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: When $\langle u,v \rangle$ is maximal and when $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ is maximal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, jacobian

**First step:**
Let $I=\langle x-y,xy \rangle \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the ideal generated by $u=x-y$ and $v=xy$.

Notice that $x^2 \in I$, since $I \ni xu+v=x(x-y)+xy=x^2-xy+xy=x^2$.

$I$ is not a radical ideal, sicne $x^2 \in I$ but $x \notin I$, hence $I$ is not a maximal ideal.

Notice that the generators of $I$, $u$ and $v$, have only one common zero, namely $(0,0)$; indeed, solving $x-y=0, xy=0$ yields $x=y, x^2=0$, so $x=0=y$.

What is the additional condition (in addition to $u$ and $v$ having only one common zero) that guarantees that $\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal?

This seems a basic result in algebraic geometry,
see the comments and answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042104/in-mathbbcx-y-if-langle-u-v-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-then-langle?rq=1) involving algebraic geometry,
in particular:

> **Known result:** "$\langle f,g \rangle$ is maximal if and only if $f=0$ and $g=0$
> have exactly one common zero and they're not tangent when they intersect."
>
> **Question 1:** Where can I find a proof for this quoted result?

**Second step:**
Let $J=\langle f,g,h \rangle$, where $f,g,h \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (still polynomials in two variables).

I wish to find a similar result to the above, something like:

> **Claim:** Assume that no pair of elements of $\{f,g,h\}$ generates a maximal ideal.
> Then,"$\langle f,g,h \rangle$ is maximal if and only if the curves $f=0,g=0,h=0$
> have exactly one common zero and at that common zero, every pair of curves intersect transversally.

> **Question 2:** Is my claim true?

Any help is welcome; thank you very much!
Now also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466846/when-langle-u-v-w-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-in-mathbbcx-y?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015828/curves-with-a-common-tangent-line

Comment: I am not sure how to find the slope ot the tangent lines at the point of intersection when $u$ (or $v$) is not of the form $u=y-f(x)$.

Comment: https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/math/calculus/implicit-differentiation-tangent-line/

Comment: Perhaps the pure algebraic condition I am looking for is just the condition concerning the slpoes of the tangents lines in the point of intersection.

Comment: I guess we should divide into two cases: (1) Two of $\{u,v,w\}$ already generate a maximal ideal. (2) No two of $\{u,v,w\}$ generate a maximal ideal, and in this case it seems more reasonable that my claim holds. Notice that my claim does not hold in case (1), for example: $u=y,v=x^2+x,w=x$; here $u$ and $w$ already generate a maximal ideal, and $v$ and $w$ are tangent at $(0,0)$.